# How do you remove unrequired runtimes when using onnxruntime in a dotnet project?

Tags: msbuild, onnxruntime

We are using the `Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime` nuget package in a very small console app; which is carrying 321MB of additional files in it's runtimes folder, most of which appear to be for ios and linux.

We are only going to be running on x64 servers, is there a flag to be added to the `dotnet publish` that allows us to target `x86` and drop the bloat?

Comment: Sounds like you may want [Native AOT deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows)